# How do I convert BindingSource.DataSource to my custom object?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom dataset style class defined as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LibrarySort.Data
{
  public class LibraryData
  {
    private AlbumList albums;
    public AlbumList Albums { get { return albums; } }

    public LibraryData()
    {
      this.albums = new AlbumList();
      this.albums.AllowEdit = true;
      this.Albums.AllowNew = true;
      this.Albums.AllowRemove = true;
    }

    public void FillAll()
    {
      this.Albums.Fill();
    }
  }

  public class AlbumList : BindingList<Album>
  {
    public AlbumList()
    {
    }

    public void Fill()
    {
      int id = 1;
      Album album1 = new Album();
      album1.Id = id++;
      album1.Artist = "Classical Piano Artist";
      album1.Download = true;
      album1.Person = null;
      album1.Price = (decimal?)3.49;
      album1.Tags.Add("classical");
      album1.Tags.Add("piano");
      album1.Title = "Classical Piano";
      Album album2 = new Album();
      album2.Id = id++;
      album2.Artist = "Thrash Metal Artist";
      album2.Download = false;
      album2.Person = null;
      album2.Price = (decimal?)7.99;
      album2.Tags.Add("thrash metal");
      album2.Title = "Thrash Metal";

      this.Items.Add(album1);
      this.Items.Add(album2);
    }
  }
}
```

I also a have Form object that inside a TabControl has a DataGridView. In the designer, I created a BindingSource and used the Add Project Data Source to create a source from the top level LibraryData object. I then bind the DataGridView to the "Albums" data member, all in the designer, and the columns get populated in the designer as expected.

When running the code, the table isn't populated, which makes sense as the Fill() hasn't been run. So I create a Load event handler for the form as follows:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LibraryData data = (LibraryData)bindingSource.DataSource;
  data.FillAll();
}
```

However on run I get the following in MainForm_Load():

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
Message="Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'LibrarySort.Data.LibraryData'

I've Googled extensively on this, and in StackOverflow but no luck. Am I missing something?

Update: DataSource is definitely non-null. Also interestingly, in the designer code I see this:

```
this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(LibrarySort.Data.LibraryData);
```

Update 2: Album class and parent Item:

```
namespace LibrarySort.Data
{
  public class Album : Item
  {
    bool download = false;
    public bool Download { get { return download; } set { download = value; } }

    string artist = null;
    public string Artist { get { return artist; } set { artist = value; } }
  }
}

namespace LibrarySort.Data
{
  public class Item
  {
    int id = -1;
    public int Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }

    // FK to Person that currently has possession of item
    int? person = null;
    public int? Person { get { return person; } set { person = value; } }

    string title = null;
    public string Title { get { return title; } set { title = value; } }

    decimal? price = null;
    public decimal? Price { get { return price; } set { price = value; } }

    State state = State.Owned;
    public State State { get { return state; } set { state = value; } }

    List<string> tags = null;
    public List<string> Tags
    {
      get
      {
        if (tags == null)
          tags = new List<string>();
        return tags;
      }
      // No set needed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you came across this example? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms132679.aspx

Comment: @Derek I did see that example, but it assumes you only want one list. In my project I will have several lists, with two having a parent/child relation, hence why I created a parent object to contain all lists.

Comment: Can you post the Album class please. I'm assuming that Album has a property called Tags that is a List object also?

Comment: Your data source is being set wrong. `this.bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(LibrarySort.Data.LibraryData);` is setting your datasource to a `System.Type` instance, not a `LibraryData` instance.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Understood, but it was the designer that set that code. Have I done something wrong in the designer?

Comment: IIRC, the designer does that so that you can get design-time support for the schema in your data source; it expects you to set the datasource in code, at run-time, to an instance of your object.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Thanks, this cleared up my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that although you have a binding source on your form, you have not set the datasource of the binding source.

Assuming that `bindingSource` is the `datasource` you dropped on your form, then try the following in the `MainForm_Load`:

```
LibraryData data = new LibraryData();
data.FillAll();
bindingSource.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but it means the designer doesn't pick up the columns properly. It all appears fine in the UI though. I'll use this if there's not a designer-style solution

Comment: Given the comments from @MichaelEdenfield above, it seems this is the correct solution. Thanks